# How to calibrate internal temperature sensor value in STM32 L496ZGT4

Tags: stm32, sensors, temperature, adc

I'm creating simple project using STM32 L946ZGT4. I'd like to use the internal temperature sensor. I configured ADC and i can get value from this. My problem is with calibrate this sensor. Using Reference Manual and Datasheet instructions my final value in celsius degrees equals -17. The ADC value is about 800. Here is my code for sensor calibrating.

```c
    #include "Myfun.h"
    #include "HD44780.h"
    
    extern uint16_t tab[100];
    char buf[16];
    float sum, avg;
    
    #define TS_CAL1((uint16_t*)((uint32_t) 0x1FFF75A8))
    #define TS_CAL2((uint16_t*)((uint32_t) 0x1FFF75CA))
    #define TS_CAL1_TEMP 30.0 f
    #define TS_CAL2_TEMP 130.0 f
    
    int32_t temperature;
    
    int main(void)
    {
        SysTick_Config(4000000 / 1000);
        LCD_Init();
        Led_Conf();
        ADC_Conf_DMA_TempSensor();
        while (1)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100;)
            {
                sum = sum + tab[i];
                ++i;
            }
            avg = sum / 100;    // here is my value from ADC
            temperature = (int32_t)(((TS_CAL2_TEMP - TS_CAL1_TEMP) / ((float)(*TS_CAL2) - (float)(*TS_CAL1))) *
                (avg - (float)(*TS_CAL1)) + 30.0);
            sprintf(buf, "%d C", temperature);
    
            LCD_Clear();
            LCD_WriteText(buf);
    
            delay_ms(60);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your ADC reading to volt by:

```
ADC_value / ADC_maxvalue * ADC_refvoltage
```

with
ADC_value: the value you get back from the ADC
ADC_maxvalue: 2^12 = 4096, when you are sampling in the 12-bit mode
ADC_revoltage: 3.3 Volt, typically - except you are using a different reference voltage

Then apply the formula from the datasheet, chapter "Electrical Characteristics" --> "Operating Conditions" --> "Temperature Sensor", where you find the offset and the scale (plus the formula) to convert the voltage to temperature ...